# How to load plugin static data from cloudfront

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, cdn

I am moving my site's static content data to Amazon S3+ CloudFront and i am successful in doing this for most part of my site (no plugin used) except for the plugin section.

For the plugin i am thinking to rewrite its URL so that they can be mapped with my Amazon CDN URL.
for e.g 
as of now all images/css and js file for the plugin are served with this URL

```
www.myblog.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/file(s)
```

and my plan is to reqwrite such URL's with

```
www.mycdn.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/file(s)
```

not sure how this can be done in wordpress, any pointer will really be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are already plugins to do the rewrites. For example, [CDN Linker](https://github.com/wmark/CDN-Linker). By default, it loads / rewrites the static content for 'wp-includes' and 'wp-content'. You may change this default behaviour after the installation / activation or fork it to let this plugin rewrite only the data from the plugins directory.

Comment: i used that plugin but there were certain issues with that which prevented me to use this plugin.